# Error response for REST API

Tags: json, spring, rest

Below is the error response that my API is returning to the client:

```
{
    "statusCode": "400",
    "errors": [
         {
             "errorCode": "50009",
             "fieldName": "bookingDate",
             "errorMsg": "Input bookingDate must lie in the bracket: 20 Jan - 27 Jan, 2018"
         }
     ]
}
```

Client cannot show the errorMsg returned by the API in the UI, but it needs bracket information i.e. (20 Jan - 27 Jan, 2018) while forming some more meaning errorMsg. So, client has to extract bracket information from the API response.

But, this can break the client's functionality if the text of the errorMsg is changed.
So, to make client's life easy, I would like to change the error response slightly like this:

```
{
    "statusCode": "400",
    "errors": [
         {
             "errorCode": "50009",
             "fieldName": "bookingDate",
             "errorMsg": "Input bookingDate must lie in the bracket: 20 Jan - 27 Jan, 2018",
             "startDate": "20 Jan 2018",
             "endDate": "27 Jan 2018"
         }
     ]
}
```

So, is it the right way to add startDate and endDate into the error response (just for the client's benefit) or is there any other better way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can the client not display the errorMsg? A good pattern for input validating REST APIs is to return at least one human readable validation error message which does not reveal internal information (e.g. stack traces etc.)

Comment: The client of this API is UI which supports multiple languages. This API returns errorMsg in English and hence cannot be shown in the UI when the language selected by user is lets say, German.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are free whatever information you want to add to your error response. If you it's really useful to you, there is no reason not to. Facebook does so. On the other hand I would try to not bloat an error response.

A well designed and decoupled REST API **implies** most of the error reasons with the help of the standard definitions of the HTTP error codes, which still should be documented within the API documentation. Given this, a developer of a client is able to know the exact error only by parsing the error status.

This also means that a client developer needs to check whatever he can, straight away, without sending any request to the back end. For example if the given date range is valid.

Stating this, if a returning error code cannot be used to figure out the exact problem of the request, the design of the API interface **might** be not optimal.

Although as REST is only a concept, it's nearly impossible to implement a perfect RESTfull API, therefor there are always exceptions, IMHO.

Comment: I tend to disagree with *a developer of a client is able to know the exact error only by parsing the error status*. For validating REST API, this will usually **not** be the case. The error status will only indicate that the input was invalid (usually with a `400` code), but not indicate **what exactly** was invalid (e.g. wrong format, wrong range etc.). You would have to add lots of HTTP status codes for this...

Comment: Wrong format and stuff usually should be checked already by the front end. My mentioned idea, is an ideal. This means in reality probably not reasonable achievable, but one should tend to. IHMO

Comment: @HerrDerb Well, there may be lots of cases where validation requires server-side information (e.g. user name already exists). Of course, you could add endpoints to enable the UI to perform the validation... But then, you are moving business logic into the UI, which many consider kind of anti-pattern. I agree that one should try to achieve the mentioned ideal, but especially for this kind of endpoint, there are definitely tradeoffs you cannot avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question tends to attract opinion-based answers, I will try to give some perhaps helpful hints.

Your API seems to validate user input. This input may be invalid for various reasons (e.g. no parseable date, date in the past etc.). This can never be reflected only via HTTP status codes and as such, returning an HTTP 400 **and** a validation error message, as you already do, is good practice.

This validation error message should be human-readable and it should be okay for the client to display it to the user. If a field name is included (as it is in your example), the client can even highlight the associated input field and display the error message next to it.

If the consumer of your API is not a UI, but some kind of automated service, then error related technical fields may fit the needs more. (And this is where opinions come into play: Many people say that the API should be agnostic of the consuming client types). But I think in your case, you should rather investigate why the client is unable to display the `errorMsg` - this should be the best and most flexible way to go to add additional validations in the future.

Comment: The error message is to be shown in the UI. But UI is supporting multiple languages depending upon the user's language of preference. API is returning response only in English. UI has to convert this errorMsg (which comes in English) into the user's preferred language.

Comment: @Azim Depending on your application architecture, you could move localization to your API backend, and request desired language via a standard `Accept-Language` header. This would mean a tigher coupling between API and frontend, so perhaps this may not be feasible in your case. (JIRA, as an example, gets most, if not all, UI strings from its backend via REST API calls.)

Comment: Localization on API side is fine but that needs to be implemented, which is not going to happen in near future. This question is mainly about whether adding startDate and endDate in the error response is fine or not. Please edit your answer and throw some more light over this.
Thanks :)

Comment: @Azim: Sorry, I cannot edit my answer towards this, as this, in the end, would be just my opinion. I tried to give some hints which may help you in decision making. You are free to find my answer not helpful, but this is all I can offer, sorry.